# Using RDP with a passwordless Microsoft Account

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I am trying to use Remote Desktop from my iPad to the Remote computer on the same network which is using Windows 11 Pro. The Microsoft Account I am using is a passwordless account and  I sign in using a PIN or a fingerprint. If I use the email address and PIN as a combination, it does not work. Does RDP support Passwordless logins yet?

Comment: No, RDP does not support passwordless logins yet. You need to create a local account on the remote machine and use its login details for RDP.

Comment: Microsoft Accounts cannot be an empty password. I am not sure what actually is going on but there is a strong chance your local account is not actually linked to your Microsoft Account

Comment: @Ramhound: See for example [How to Go Passwordless on Your Microsoft Account](https://www.wired.com/story/how-to-no-password-microsoft-account/). Microsoft now dislikes passwords.

Comment: This might still work: On the target computer, run `regedit` and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` and set `LimitBlankPasswordUse` to the value of `0` to enable empty passwords on the network.